# EF Core many to zero relationship configuration

Tags: entity-framework-core

How can I prevent EF Core migrations from adding a shadow property to TimeZone:

```
public partial class InitialCreate : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Core_TimeZone",
            schema: "dbo",
            columns: table => new
            {
                StateOrProvinceId = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
                ...
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Core_TimeZone", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Core_TimeZone_Core_StateOrProvince_StateOrProvinceId",
                    column: x => x.StateOrProvinceId,
                    principalSchema: "dbo",
                    principalTable: "Core_StateOrProvince",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });
    }
}
```

Here are the POCO classes:

```
public partial class TimeZone : BaseEntity
{
    …
   // no StateOrProvince related properties
}


public partial class StateOrProvince : BaseEntity
{
    …
    private ICollection<Dna.NetCore.Core.BLL.Entities.Common.TimeZone> _timeZones;
    public virtual ICollection<Dna.NetCore.Core.BLL.Entities.Common.TimeZone> TimeZones
    {
        get { return _timeZones ?? (_timeZones = new List<Dna.NetCore.Core.BLL.Entities.Common.TimeZone>()); }
        set { _timeZones = value; }
    }
}
```

and the configuration class:

```
public class StateOrProvinceConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<StateOrProvince>
{
    public void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<StateOrProvince> builder)
    {
        …
        builder.HasMany(d => d.TimeZones)
               .WithOne()
               .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }
}
```

I'm getting the shadow property regardless of whether or not I include the HasMany().WithOne() configuration.

The full [source code is located in this GitHub repository](https://github.com/RandyDaddis/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/AspNetCoreMvcSampleCode.RefactoredGenericRepository/src/Dna.NetCore.Core.DAL.EFCore/Configuration/Common/StateOrProvinceConfiguration.cs).